# How to change the place of a block or region based on url path?

Tags: blocks, 7

I have a menu block and it will be displayed on all pages, but I need to change the placing of it. On certain pages (dependent on path) I need to display it above the main content, while on other pages I need to place it below the content.
I am experimenting with the context module and I was able to put the block above the content, but then on these pages, the menu shows BOTH above and below the content.

I have a solution in mind, but there must be a better way: I can set up two regions, one above and one below the content, then put the menu block in the region below the content, and set up a context to put the menu in the above region AND hide the below region. This could work, though I think there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: I think the solution might be to disable this block at `admin/structure/block` and then assign to appropriate region with the context.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7 you can achieve it using [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module as suggested by the Jack.

Steps

- Fist of all disable the **menu block** using `admin/structure/block`.

  [image]
- As you specified you need to show **menu block** in two regions, then those 2 regions(**main content** and **above the content**) must exist. If not then create it.
- Create a new context and add **menu block** based on your requirement and path.
- Showing **menu block** block in region **Content**

  [image]
- Showing **menu block** block in another region **user bar second**

  [image]

Reference :

- [create custom regions](https://drupal.org/node/171205)

Comment: +1, probably best to let context handle the placement of the block and to stop using the admin/structure/block page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the URL check logic in your theme's template.php (use theme_preprocess_page hook) and pass the result (something like $variables['isBlockAboveContent']) to the page.tpl.php and render the block where you need after checking the $isBlockAboveContent .

Hope this helps.